# Receive large XML object

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

My application receives some data from server in XML form. I parse it using `XmlPullParser`. Everything works fine. Until server sends large nested object - bitmap or file in BASE64 encoding (up to 10+Mb). On old devices with little VM heap (2.3 for example) application crashes on `String text = parser.getText();` (out of memory)

What should I do in this case?

Is there any way to get stream? Or mabey `XmlPullParser` can split it and give it to me by parts?

Comment: I had the same problem (actually even on 4.0 it still doesn't work). Unfortunately, I found no solution except writing your own XML parser to split up this String into various Strings and try to manipulate it.

Comment: i recommend using multipart server response (only references in the xml, and binary objects as other parts). This way, you avoid the bulk or parsing a 10M xml and a 10M B64

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't modify server side. I see two ways: 1 switch to sax parser as answered below; 2 modify KXmlParser due to its license does not restrict it, or write new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possiblility is to swich to [Sax Parsing](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html). The main difference being that it will not need to read the entire xml string into memory at once. Instead it will work its way through it in small chunks.

It is a bit more complex to set up, but if you search around online for things like "Android Sax Parsers example" there are some good samples to get you started. It is really not any more difficult just takes a moment to get accustomed to doing it that way instead of with a pull parser.

Comment: Note that he might run into the same problem. The SAX parser will try to convert the base64 element into a String, and chances are it will fail then also. 10MB in base64 seems unwieldy.

Comment: We use parser just to obtain data. Then we decode data and write it to a database in BLOB. Decoding is seems to be easy, if we split data and decode it by parts.